# wplayer.controls.stop(); doesnt work

Tags: c#, audio-player

I set an int called playercount as 1 at the start and did the following..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playercount++;
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = "Super Mario Bros.mp3";

        if (playercount % 2 == 0)
        {
            button2.Text = "Music Toggle: ON";
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
        else
        {
            wplayer.controls.stop();
            button2.Text = "Music Toggle: OFF";
        }


    }
```

For some reason the music stop doesn't seem to work. Is there something im doing wrongly ?

Comment: on your first click your count == 1 so count % 2 != 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `WindowsMediaPlayer` each time the button is clicked. This means that your `stop()` call will not affect the player you create on the first click which you `play()`.

You need to create the player as a class-level variable and act on that.

You `playercount` logic is a bit dubious too as InvernoMuto pointed out. Is a simple `bool` not sufficient?

```
private bool musicPlaying = false;
private WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = null;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create player only if necessary
    if(wplayer == null)
    {
        wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = "Super Mario Bros.mp3";
    }

    // toggle musicPlaying
    musicPlaying = !musicPlaying;

    if (musicPlaying)
    {
        button2.Text = "Music Toggle: ON";
        wplayer.controls.play();
    }
    else
    {
        wplayer.controls.stop();
        button2.Text = "Music Toggle: OFF";
    }
}
```